# Exception handling in AVIOContext read callbacks

Tags: exception, ffmpeg

```
m_formatCtx = avformat_alloc_context ();
uint8_t * buffer = NULL, * avio_ctx_buffer = NULL;
size_t buffer_size, avio_ctx_buffer_size = 200;
avio_ctx_buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc (avio_ctx_buffer_size * 10);
AVIOContext * avio_ctx = avio_alloc_context (avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size,                                           0,
                                           tcp, &socketRead, NULL, NULL);
```

Read video / audio information through socketRead as above.

```
int socketRead (void * ptr, uint8_t * buf, int buf_size)
{
    printf ("socketRead bufsize =% d \ n", buf_size);
    ssize_t readSize = 0;
    TCPClient * tcp = (TCPClient *) ptr;
    readSize = tcp-> read (buf, buf_size);
    return readSize;
}
```

However, if a video packet is incorrectly received in the middle,

```
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 2048
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 2048
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 4096
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 8192
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 16384
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 32768
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 65536
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 131072
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 262144
D / libnav: socketRead bufsize = 524288
```

Finally, buf_size of socketRead increases and eventually

```
A / libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x440 in tid 19369 (Thread-21565)
```

I get this error.

I want to do some other flexible processing instead of crash. I need help.

Comment: What exactly this mean "However, if a video packet is incorrectly received in the middle" ?

Comment: example) It can occur segment error when some container like mkv doesn't send mkv header.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: I want to handle some error exception during call av_read_frame function.

Comment: To me, clearly you direction is wrong. Error handling already done in FFmpeg and what happens in this case shows your project has some serious issues about design. Anyway if you persist and wanna implement your own read_frame function, you need implement open source mkv (or what the source container is) libraries which will have `read` function you can customize.

Comment: okay, I knew what you saying.